# How can I know if sever functions are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be the collection of continuous functions with domain on [a,b]. Define $f+g(t)=f(t)+g(t),0(t)=0,(\lambda f)(t)=f(t)\lambda $, then $E$ is a vector space. I want to know how to determine if several functions are linearly independent. For example, how to know if $1,e^t,e^{-t}$ are linearly independent or not?

Comment: The same way as usual: Write down constants $c_1, ..., c_3$ such that $$c_1 1 + c_2 e^t + c_3 e^{-t} = 0$$ and show that each $c_i$ is zero. This can be done by differentiating, or evaluating at carefully chosen points to get a system of equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\;a+be^t+ce^{-t}=0\;$ , this being an equality between **functions**, so

$$\begin{align*}I&\;\;\;t=0\implies a+b+c=0\\{}\\
II&\;\;\;t=1\implies a+be+ce^{-1}=0\iff ae+be^2+c=0\\{}\\
III&\;\;\;t=-1\implies a+be^{-1}+ce=0\iff ae+b+ce^2=0\end{align*}$$

Substracting eq. I from eq. II above , we get:

$$(*)\;\;\;(e-1)a+(e^2-1)b=0\stackrel{\text{why?}}\implies a+(e+1)b=0$$

But then again,  substracting eq. I from eq. III:

$$(**)\;\;(e-1)a+(e^2-1)c=0\implies a+(e+1)c=0$$

Compare ( * )-( ** ) above, substract them and get

$$(e+1)(b-c)=0\implies b=c$$

Using this in I we get $\;a=-2b\;$ , and then in II

$$(e-1)^2b=0\implies b=0\;\;\text{and we're done} $$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in order to show dependence () you need to show that there are constants $c_1, c_2, c_3$ , so that $c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^t+c_31=0$, but where $0$ is the *$0$ function*, i.e., the function with the constant value $0$.

Now, this means that the above linear combination must equal zero *for all t* .

Let's show this is not possible: we start with:

$$ c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^t+1=0 $$ ( we can always rescale so that $c_3=1$). Now, set $e^t=u$ , and let's treat $u$ as a variable. We substitute above, to get $$ \frac{c_1}{u}+c_2u+1=c_2u^2+u+c_1=0 $$.

Now, we can treat this as a quadratic in $u$, and we can find its roots by: $$\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt(1-4c_2c_1)}{2c_2} $$

which forces the condition $$ 1-4c_2c_1=1 => 4c_2c_1=0 $$.

So that we must have either $c_1=0$ or $c_2=0$, either of the cases leads to a contradiction when substituting in the top equation; considering $c_1=0$ first, we get
 $$c_2e^t+1=0 => c_2=-1/e^t $$ But this is already impossible, since this must hold *for all t* (remember that the $0$ on the right hand side is the $0$ *function* , not the number $0$).

We get a similar contradiction by assuming $c_1=1$